# How to keep shortcodes from displaying in description

Tags: php, wordpress

Using this code

```
    <?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
$descrip = strip_tags($post->post_content);
$descrip_more = '';
if (strlen($descrip) > 155) {
$descrip = substr($descrip,0,155);
$descrip_more = ' ...';
}
$descrip = str_replace('"', '', $descrip);
$descrip = str_replace("'", '', $descrip);
$descripwords = preg_split('/[\n\r\t ]+/', $descrip, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
array_pop($descripwords);
$descrip = implode(' ', $descripwords) . $descrip_more; 
echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$descrip.'">';
?>
```

Which outputs someething like this in my header:

```
<meta name="description" content="[wptabs mode=horizontal background=false] [wptabtitle]     English Lyrics[/wptabtitle] [wptabcontent]Speed Circus Yeah A-yoWOO TAEWOON with the am I     ...">
```

I was wondering if I could add something to the code that would get rid of the shortcodes? and perhaps anything in them?

Maybe out it like this?

```
<meta name="description" content="Speed Circus Yeah A-yoWOO TAEWOON with the am I     ...">
```

Answer (score 1):

What need to do is render the post and not display the post contents. There's a slight difference in here.

You should try using:

```
apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

Instead of:

```
$post->post_content
```

When you apply filters to the content you get the post as it is displayed to the user, while $post->post_content displays the raw content for the post.

Comment: That wouldn't be appropriate here.

Comment: I see your point, didn't payed attention to what the shortcodes are actually doing. He is using shortcodes to format text, I thought shortcodes were generating content.

Comment: This starts showing DIVs and things like that, instead of the short code, it shows like.. the css of the of the code

    <meta name="description" content="<div id=wp-tabs-1 class=wp-   tabs wpui-dark wpui-styles wpui-tabs-horizontal wpui-no-background data-style=wpui-dark> <h3 class=wp-tab-title> ...">

Comment: It wouldn't be appropriate because the OP is echoing the content inside a meta element. He needs to strip all tags rather than add more which is the case if he opted to use the_content filter. If he wanted to process shortcodes he'd be better using `do_shortcode()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function to remove shortcodes.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes

Put this just before the echo:

```
$descrip = strip_shortcodes( $descrip );
```

Given that you're outputting this in an attribute you should use the function for escaping attributes. `esc_attr()`. You can find out more about that here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr

Complete example based on your code and comments left on my answer:

```
 <?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
$descrip = strip_tags( $post->post_content );
$descrip_more = '';
if (strlen($descrip) > 155) {
    $descrip = substr($descrip,0,155);
    $descrip_more = ' ...';
}
$descrip = str_replace('"', '', $descrip);
$descrip = str_replace("'", '', $descrip);

$descripwords = preg_split('/[\n\r\t ]+/', $descrip, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
array_pop($descripwords);
$descrip = implode(' ', $descripwords) . $descrip_more; 
$descrip = strip_shortcodes( $descrip );

echo '<meta name="description" content="' . esc_attr( get_the_title( $post->ID ) . trim( $descrip ) ) . '">';
?>
```

Comment: I apologize, but I think "<?php strip_shortcodes( $content ); ?>
" is it, if so, where do I place it? Maybe specifically if you can? I'm not too good with these kinds of things

Comment: Would you also happen to know how I could include the post title in the content area? When I try adding it, it actually show the php code got get_the_title in the source code

Comment: @user2320262 do you mean something like echoing the title attribute? like explained in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

Comment: Yes, but when I add it to the code like this, <meta name="description" content="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>, '.$descrip.'">,
It shows the <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> in the source code instead of the title itself

Comment: You're already echoing a value but are including tags. I'll update my answer to show you a complete version.

Comment: Thank you!!!! It works great!!! But it still shows the spaces between the two, is there a way to get of that space? "<meta name="description" content="UVERWORLD &#8211; NANO SECOND LYRICS   (space) Everything year life dont know why but sore ga gensō no mama de owatte itte yoi wake nai darou tomonau kizu ...">

Comment: I've made a slight tweak to my code which should remove the space. Please copy again.